# My CNN network validation accuracy get stuck at epoch 2 and doesn't change

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So I am training a CNN network to label 1500 matrixes between two classes (750 vs 750). The matrixes are all 9x200 and I am treating them in the code as images with 1 channel (9, 200, 1) that I transform in (200,200,1) padding with 0.

The model architecture is this:

```
model= tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, input_shape=(200, 200, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid'))



model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
metrics='binary_accuracy')
```

I am using a custom generator:

```
class Generator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, DATASET_PATH, BATCH_SIZE=32, shuffle_images=True, image_min_side=8):

        self.batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
        self.shuffle_images = shuffle_images
        self.image_min_side = image_min_side
        self.load_image_paths_labels(DATASET_PATH)
        self.create_image_groups()
    
    def load_image_paths_labels(self, DATASET_PATH):
        
        classes = os.listdir(DATASET_PATH)
        lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
        lb.fit(classes)

        self.image_paths = []
        self.image_labels = []
        for class_name in classes:
            class_path = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, class_name)
            for image_file_name in os.listdir(class_path):
                self.image_paths.append(os.path.join(class_path, image_file_name))
                self.image_labels.append(class_name)

        self.image_labels = np.array(lb.transform(self.image_labels), dtype='float32')
        
        assert len(self.image_paths) == len(self.image_labels)

    def create_image_groups(self):
        if self.shuffle_images:
            Randomly shuffle dataset
            seed = 4321
            np.random.seed(seed)
            np.random.shuffle(self.image_paths)
            np.random.seed(seed)
            np.random.shuffle(self.image_labels)

        # Divide image_paths and image_labels into groups of BATCH_SIZE
        self.image_groups = [[self.image_paths[x % len(self.image_paths)] for x in range(i, i + self.batch_size)]
                              for i in range(0, len(self.image_paths), self.batch_size)]
        self.label_groups = [[self.image_labels[x % len(self.image_labels)] for x in range(i, i + self.batch_size)]
                              for i in range(0, len(self.image_labels), self.batch_size)]


    def load_images(self, image_group):

        images = []
        for image_path in image_group:
            img = np.genfromtxt(image_path,delimiter=',',skip_header=1)
            img = np.absolute(img)/100
            img = img[..., np.newaxis]
            images.append(img)

        return images

    def construct_image_batch(self, image_group):
        max_shape = (200,200,1)
        # construct an image batch object
        image_batch = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + max_shape, dtype='float32')

        # copy all images to the upper left part of the image batch object
        for image_index, image in enumerate(image_group):
            image_batch[image_index, :image.shape[0], :image.shape[1], :image.shape[2]] = image

        return image_batch
    
    def __len__(self):
        """
        Number of batches for generator.
        """

        return len(self.image_groups)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """
        Keras sequence method for generating batches.
        """
        image_group = self.image_groups[index]
        label_group = self.label_groups[index]
        images = self.load_images(image_group)
        image_batch = self.construct_image_batch(images)

        return np.array(image_batch), np.array(label_group)
```

I tried different optimizers (Adam, SGD, RMSprop) trying different learning rates where possible.

I also tried to not pad my matrixes using them as input (9,200,1).

For the training:

```
train_dir = 'dataset/train'
val_dir = 'dataset/val'

BATCH_SIZE=64


train_generator = Generator(train_dir, BATCH_SIZE, shuffle_images=True, image_min_side=1)
val_generator = Generator(val_dir, 15, shuffle_images=True, image_min_side=1)


history = model.fit(train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
epochs=10,
verbose=1,
validation_data = val_generator,
validation_steps=len(val_generator))
```

In the output the val_accuracy get stuck at second epochs and never change:

```
Epoch 1/10
15/15 [==============================] - 17s 1s/step - loss: 0.7049 - binary_accuracy: 0.4938 - val_loss: 0.6925 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/10
15/15 [==============================] - 17s 1s/step - loss: 0.6931 - binary_accuracy: 0.5156 - val_loss: 0.6897 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/10
15/15 [==============================] - 17s 1s/step - loss: 0.6928 - binary_accuracy: 0.5365 - val_loss: 0.6860 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 4/10
15/15 [==============================] - 17s 1s/step - loss: 0.6927 - binary_accuracy: 0.5375 - val_loss: 0.6853 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 5/10
15/15 [==============================] - 17s 1s/step - loss: 0.6922 - binary_accuracy: 0.5375 - val_loss: 0.6847 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 6/10
15/15 [==============================] - 19s 1s/step - loss: 0.6933 - binary_accuracy: 0.5333 - val_loss: 0.6837 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 7/10
15/15 [==============================] - 18s 1s/step - loss: 0.6919 - binary_accuracy: 0.5375 - val_loss: 0.6836 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 8/10
15/15 [==============================] - 19s 1s/step - loss: 0.6927 - binary_accuracy: 0.5250 - val_loss: 0.6841 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 9/10
15/15 [==============================] - 19s 1s/step - loss: 0.6919 - binary_accuracy: 0.5323 - val_loss: 0.6848 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 10/10
15/15 [==============================] - 19s 1s/step - loss: 0.6916 - binary_accuracy: 0.5375 - val_loss: 0.6828 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
```

In the end to investigate if it is a problem with my dataset I created dummy matrixes, filled with 100 for label 1 and 1 for label 2. The output I reported above is from this last try but it's very similar with my dataset.

I spent the last week reading all the similar questions and tried all the proposed solutions and workaround but nothing changed.
I checked also manually that each batch was balanced between the two classes and that each folder contains the correct data.

I'm kinda a newbie with NN and any advice will be very appreciated.

I tried Tensorflow 2.2 and 2.4, to assess that this is not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know if 2D CNN layers are appropriate for your task without more context. The implicit assumption for choosing a CNN layer is that there's local context that can be combined at each layer to model your classes. Said another way, if there's nothing specific about your data that tells you that observations close in proximity (in your (9,200,1) representation) would create a pattern you're trying to pick up on, then you might consider a different model architecture. Maybe just start with a dense network connected to your data.

Why are you converting it from 9x200x1 to 200x200x1? If I understand what you're doing correctly, you're introducing 22X as many zeros as you have data. That could make it really hard for a model to learn something.

Lastly, always start with the simplest model you can. They are easier to diagnose, and you can see better how the changes you make impact model metrics. You're going to have to train more than one variant to get to a model that works well, more than likely. Starting with 5 CNN layers and a huge Dense layer might be overkill for your problem even if you've checked off all the assumptions for using a particular architecture.

Comment: Hi, the idea of using a 2d cnn architecture came from the fact that I already use those matrix to produce heat maps that apparently show very different patterns between the two classes. I wanted to see if it was possible to create a model to distinguish between those classes. I was thinking about problem with my generator because everytime I try to train the model it always get stuck at one value that usually represent the distribution of the two classes, like it is just tossing a count without any improvemente

Comment: What you're describing is can happen when the model you're training and the features you're using are not compatible. It actually looks like your model is not learning. I don't think it's your generator. I think its your architecture, and the transform you're using on the data. Try to flatten your matrix, and use a single dense layer that's half as big as your inputs and see if your model starts learning. If so, then you can slowly start to iterate with bigger more complex models. That's how you build up intuition for what can work with models like this.

Comment: Don't zero pad the matrices before you flatten them. That's not adding any information to the system.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. Actually I did reduce the complexity of architecture and the model started to learn. Right now I'm stuck at roughly 65% accuracy and every layer I've tried to add just reduced this value.  Guess the data too has its limit. Right now I'm trying to add something to the data creation. The final architecture is just  flatten->dense-> dense-> out.